# Expected distance in a continuous random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, random, random-walk

Consider a random process $X=X_1,X_2,\ldots X_n$ such that $X_0=0^d$ and $\forall i:X_i\in\mathbb R^d$.

For $i\ge 1$, The value of $X_i$ is determined by moving a ($\ell_2$) distance of (exactly) $1$, in a random direction, from $X_{i-1}$.

> What is $\mathbb E[|X_n|]$ - the expected ($\ell_2$) distance the process makes from the origin?

---

Obviously, for $d=1$ this is a standard 1D integer random walk and we have $\mathbb E[|X_n|]=O(\sqrt n)$.

Comment: Since $X_n = Y_1 + Y_2 + ... + Y_n$ with $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ i.i.d. zero mean and unit variance, it is easier to (exactly) compute $E[||X_n||^2]$.  You can then use $E[||X_n||] \leq \sqrt{E[||X_n||^2]}$.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. This seems to imply a $O(\sqrt n)$ bound on the distance, same as in the 1D case. I was wondering though what is the dependence on $d$. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where you able to compute $E[||X_n||^2]$? For that one, the answer does not depend on the dimension $d$.

Comment: @Michael - Isn't $\mathbb E[|X_n^2|]=n$ trivial (as the $Y_i$'s have zero mean and independent)?

Comment: Yes, $E[||X_n||^2] =n$, and so this answer has no dependence on $d$.  The dependence on $d$ has already been compensated for by assuming the $d$-dimensional $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ vectors satisfy $\sum_{j=1}^d Y_{ij}^2=1$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, where $Y_i=(Y_{i1}, ..., Y_{id})$.

Comment: @Michael - indeed, the expectation of $X_n^2$ does not depend on $n$. But $\sqrt{E[|X_n^2|]}$ is just a lower bound on the expectation of $|X_n|$, right? Why does it imply that $\mathbb E[|X_n|]$ is also independent of $d$? e.g., why can't be something like $\sqrt {n/d}$?

Comment: @Michael - for example, consider $n=2, d \gg 1$. if $d$ is large, $\langle Y_1, Y_2\rangle$ is near-zero, and thus we'll likely get $|X_2|\approx\sqrt 2$. If $d=1$, with probability 1/2, $X_2=0$ and otherwise $|X_2|=2$. This gives $\mathbb E[|X_2|]=1$.

Comment: So $E[||X_n||] \leq \sqrt{n}$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.  It seems harder to get a lower bound, you can use the fact that $E[||X_n||^2] = n$ and $||X_n||\leq n$ with prob 1 to conclude $n= E[||X_n||^2] \leq E[||X_n|| n]= nE[||X_n||]$ and so $E[||X_n||] \geq 1$. This is of course a very loose lower bound.

Comment: I believe there is a "central limit theorem for iid random vectors" that says $\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ converges in distribution to a vector Gaussian with zero mean and covariance given by the covariance of $Y_1$. In that case $X_n \approx \sqrt{n} G_n$ where $G_n$ is a Gaussian random vector with zero mean and covariance matrix the same as $Y_1$, so $E[||X_n||] \approx \sqrt{n}E[||G_n||]$.

Comment: @Michael - thanks for the answer, but doesn't the central limit theorem assumes here that $n\gg d$? What happens otherwise?

Comment: Since you were communicating ideas with $O(\sqrt{n})$ language, it seemed you were interested in asymptotic results for large $n$. For small values of $n$ you are forced to either compute the thing exactly, or give some other bounds.